# Simplifying a summation. Binomial theorem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-theorem

> Simplify the sum
> $$
> \sum_{
> \substack{
> i, j, k \geq 0 \text{ and }
> i+j+2k=r
> }}
> (-1)^i \binom{n}{i} \binom{n}{j} \binom{n}{k} 
> $$
> for n, r $\in$ N .

I know that it can be simplified to
$$
[x^r] (1+x)^n(1-x)^n(1+x^2)^n = [x^r] (1-x^2)^n(1+x^2)^n = [x^r] (1-x^4)^n
$$
which gives $\binom{n}{\frac{r}{4}} (-1)^{\frac{r}{4}}$ if $4|r$ and $0$ otherwise.

But how do I get to that point?

I tried writing
$$
\sum_{n} \left( \sum_{i} (-1)^i \binom{n}{i}   \sum_{j}   \binom{n}{j}   \sum_{k}  \binom{n}{k} \right)x^n
$$

so I can use binomial theorem, but then I would need three $x^n$'s total to use theorem three times.

Thanks.

Comment: It is just how you multiply ([multiplication of power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Multiplication_and_division)). The coefficients of $(1+x)^n$ are $\binom{n}{j}$, the coefficients of $(1-x)^n$ are $(-1)^i\binom{n}{i}$, the coefficients of $(1+x^2)^n$ are $0$ for odd degree and $\binom{n}{k}$ for degree $2k$. In the product, the degree $r$ will add the products of the coefficients, for the degrees $i,j,2k$ that can add up to degree $r$. So, all ways to get $i+j+2k=r$.

Comment: Which of your two steps don't you undetstand? The 1st one ("I know that it can be simplified...") or the second one ("which gives...")?

Comment: The first one, meaning how to get $(1+x)^n(1-x)^n(1+x^2)^n$. @AnneBauval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(1+x)^n(1-x)^n(1+x^2)^n&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom njx^j
\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni(-x)^i
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(x^2)^k\\&=
\sum_{r=0}^{4n}x^r\sum_{i, j, k \ge0\atop
i+j+2k=r}(-1)^i\binom ni\binom nj\binom nk
\end{align}$$